# Jekyll date permalink different from post dat

Tags: wordpress, jekyll

I imported my blog from wordpress into jekyll, but the permanent links are inconsistent. Here's one example:

my post ([full file](https://github.com/fabiopereira/fabiopereirame_jekyll_mickey_blog/blob/master/_posts/2011-10-19-tw-ssc-deep-sea-fishing.html))

```
wordpress_url: http://fabiopereira.me/blog/2011/10/19/tw-ssc-deep-sea-fishing/
date: '2011-10-19 05:09:57 +1100'
date_gmt: '2011-10-19 12:09:57 +1100'
```

is generating the link
blog/2011/10/18/tw-ssc-deep-sea-fishing/

## The problem is the date

Instead of 2011/10/**19**/ in the url, it's generating 2011/10/**18**/

## For reference

```
my jekyll _config.yml
permalink:           /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title
timezone:            Asia/Sydney # eg. Asia/Kathmandu
locale:              en_AU # eg. en_us
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know think this post is on-topic for Stack Overflow, and should probably be migrated to SuperUser or somewhere more appropriate.

Nevertheless, I see two possible problems:

### date_gmt

Your post file contains both `date` and `date_gmt`. I'm not sure you want to set both. You probably only want to *read* `date_gmt`, rather than writing it.

Even if you do write it, you probably want to make sure your `date_gmt` doesn't have a local time offset (in your example above, it has the same +11 offset that your `date` has).

### Timezone

I suspect that Jekyll doesn't complain when you set a timezone that doesn't exist. I suspect you'll get the same results with "Fiction/Utopia" as you do for "Asia/Sydney" (which I don't think is one of the standard locations in the database). Try "Australia/Sydney" instead (or maybe "Pacific/Sydney", I'm on mobile and I don't have the list to hand right now).

Good luck!